# How to use the dates and times functions for preparing a sequence of 4 times per day, so every 6 hours

Tags: r, date, datetime, posixct

With the help of the posixct I can make a series of  e.g. year-month-day-hour, but  I cannot say at by e.g. every 6 hours, that I would need.

So, how to build up a date&time series that contain the followings:

```
c("2012-09-01 03","2012-09-01 09","2012-09-01 15","2012-09-01 21" ,"2012-09-02 03","2012-09-02 09","2012-09-02 15","2012-09-02 21")
```

Sorry, if it is evident, I could not find the answer anywhere!

Thanks,
Gabi

**Edit**

Thank you for your help. However, even I tried to plot my data based on my new date & times and try to use `axis.Date` and `labDates` to lab the x, I always receive error saying that this new creation (that I called mydate) is not a Date - saying:

> Error in seq.Date(as.Date("01/09/2012 03", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H"), tail(mydate, : 'to' must be a "Date" object ... as I coded: labDates <- seq(as.Date("01/09/2012 03", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H"), tail(mydate, 1),by = "months").

As mydate, I have tried both the first and the second solutions.

Actually, I cannot even plot them, but I have found that I can:

```
mydate <- seq(as.POSIXct("01-09-2012 03", format = "%d-%m-%Y %H"), by = "6 hour", length = 4500)
```

with this I can plot, but cannot label the x axle...

Comment: Sorry about my question. Originally, it was longer, showing my code and more outputs, but I just could not send it. There were always some mistake in my mail.

Comment: Thank you StuartLC! (Sorry about my monumental ignorance connected with the Stackoverflow and its rules. I have totally lost in it, and could not even managed to send a part of my program. I just still need a help in this plotting part.)

Answer (score 1):

We can try `seq`

```
format(seq(as.POSIXct('2012-09-01 03', format='%Y-%m-%d %H'), 
         length.out=8, by = '6 hour'), '%Y-%m-%d %H')
#[1] "2012-09-01 03" "2012-09-01 09" "2012-09-01 15" "2012-09-01 21"
#[5] "2012-09-02 03" "2012-09-02 09" "2012-09-02 15" "2012-09-02 21"
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that relies on the `lubridate` package instead of using `seq()`:

```
library(lubridate)
format(ymd_h("2012-09-01 03") + hours(6 * (0:7)), "%Y-%m-%d %H")
```